Proving the Set of Periodic Functions with Restrictions Form a Vector Space
I understand that a set of periodic functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be a vector space because the set is not closed under the sum of the functions, as discussed here. However, I believe a set of periodic functions with some restrictions can indeed form a vector space (a trivial example), though I am not sure if the condition that the set is closed under the summation is sufficient.
The argument is as follows:
Consider a set $G_{\pi,r}$:
$$G_{\pi,r} := \{g \mid \text{$g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous, periodic function with period } \pi r\} \text{ where } r \in \mathbb{Q}^+$$
Recall that a function is periodic if there exists a real number $P \> 0$ such that $g(x+P)= g(x) \text{ for all } x \in \mathbb{R}$. Note that $C(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the set of all continuous function, so $G_{\pi,r} \subset C(\mathbb{R})$. We want to show that $G_{\pi,r}$ is a subspace of $C(\mathbb{R})$. We know from definition that all constant functions must be a member of $G_{\pi,r}$. In particular, $g(x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is a member of $G_{\pi,r}$; so, $G_{\pi,r}$ is a nonempty set. We can skip the fact that the set is indeed closed under scalar multiplication.
The Problem:
Consider $g_{1},g_{2} \in G_{\pi,r}$, where the period for $g_{1}$ and $g_{2}$ are $\pi r_{1}$ and $\pi r_{2}$ respectively. Their sum $$(g_{1}+g_{2})(x)=g_{1}(x)+g_2(x)=g_{1}(x + \pi r_{1})+g_{2}(x + \pi r_{1})= \text{ ?}$$
I know the sum is also a periodic function since $\frac{\pi r_{2}}{\pi r_{1}}=\frac{r_{2}}{r_{1}} \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}$. But I want to show that the period of $(g_{1}+g_{2})(x)$ is $\pi r_{3}$ for some $r_{3} \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}$ to complete the proof.

If $r_1 = \frac{p_1}{q_1}$ and $r_2 = \frac{p_2}{q_2}$ with $p_1, p_2, q_1, q_2$ all positive integers, then for any real $x$,
$$ g_1(x + \pi p_1 p_2) = g_1(x + (q_1 p_2) \pi r_1) = g_1(x) $$
$$ g_2(x + \pi p_1 p_2) = g_2(x + (p_1 q_2) \pi r_2) = g_2(x) $$
$$ (g_1 + g_2)(x + \pi p_1 p_2) = (g_1 + g_2)(x) $$
So $g_1 + g_2$ is periodic. Its period is either $0$ or $\frac{\pi p_1 p_2}{n}$ for some positive integer $n$, and $\frac{p_1 p_2}{n}$ is a positive rational number.
(Note we could replace $\pi$ with any positive real number through all this, to get another vector space of functions. This includes $1$, so the set of functions with rational period is a vector space. Also, the only use of continuity was that it is closed under scalar multiplication and vector addition, so we could drop that requirement or replace it with others like "absolutely continuous", "Lebesgue square-integrable", "smooth", and/or etc.)
